# problema pra instalar nodemon, como resolver?

Tags: node.js

ola, eu to aprendendo node.js 
porem, eu to querendo instalar o nodemon, mas ele nao instala, só fica assim

como resolver? ja procurei no google e nao conseguir instalar

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual é a versão do node e npm que tens? `node -v` e `npm -v`

Comment: node v8.4.0, npm 5.3.0

Comment: Ok, estranho. A unica coisa que me ocorre é apagares a diretoria `node_modules`, apagar o `package-lock.json`, e testar de novo. Ultimo caso tentar com o `yarn add --dev nodemon`.

Comment: não adiantou =/

Comment: Estranho. Testa colocar no package.json com uma versão mais antiga.

Comment: Tente fazer a instalação global. sudo npm install -g nodemon